# Somehow broke CPU when reapplying thermal paste but cannot understand how?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cooling, computer-building

I built a new PC using a i7 9700k, hypermaster evo 212, z390-A motherboard.

The cooler is tricky to mount for me, it requires more pressure than I expected and so the first time I removed it mid-build and reseated it.It POSTed.

Later I realised I needed to redo the paste because I broke the vacuum, so I use some Q-tips and 91% isopropyl. I did not apply too much thermal paste so that it spilt off the side of the silver metal at any time, I did wear an anti-static wrist band the whole time, I did dab the q-tip on kitchen paper before using it.

Next time I power on the motherboard shows a CPU error LED and the fans kept stopping and starting.

I have tried reseating the CPU many times, which resulted in 1 difference - since then the board does not turn off and on - it stays on with the LED light on.

I bought a new motherboard in the hopes this was the culprit - same issue. The CPU must be broken? I just dont understand how I possibly could have broken it?

Edit: I also always cleaned any thermal paste off with the CPU still in the socket to prevent anything getting in there.

Comment: Have any of the pins on the CPU become damage, can you see any physical damage at all. Use a magnifying glass to check.

Comment: There are no pins on i7s @Naz

Comment: The only way I can understand this is if the cooler applied too much pressure. It does take some pressure to mount it and the arms of the mount actually bend a little.

Comment: Are you sure all connectors are plugged in properly, i've installed AMD processors in the past that have required serious pressure but can;t image it damaging the CPU if the pressure is consistently applied over the chip.

Comment: What is more likely is that pins are bent, if you suspect a bad CPU, use the warranty period to your advantage.

Comment: I believe I broke it by not applying consistent pressure when mounting the cooler, or it just arrived with issues. I did have strange display issues on the BIOS screen the single time the CPU posted so I assume it just had issues when it arrived.